# How can a Gossen Sixtomat light meter work without electricity?

Tags: light, metering, history, power-supply, light-meter

I owned an old [Gossen Sixtomat](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Sixtomat) and I am wondering if there is a battery cell or not in this device.

If there is no battery I am wondering how this could work without energy. 
I know some materials can generate electricity from the sun (e.g solar cells) but if there is not to much light, how it can still work?

I tried in my flat with a small diffused light and it can measure quite well the exposure time and aperture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is linked right there http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Selenium_meter from your link: the light meter works with a photoelectric cell. The brighter it is, the more energy it produces. Evidently, it is sensitive enough to work in closed rooms.

Comment: So what's the color finder gimmick?

Comment: It isn't so much that the cell is sensitive, because early cells weren't particularly efficient. The meter (the mechanical component with the needle) is lightweight, doesn't have a heavy return spring and requires a very tiny amount of current to make it move.